# How to compress multiple lines into single/fewer lines using regular expression or wildcard character?

Tags: regex, wildcard, text-processing, pattern-recognition

I want to compress multiple lines of string having some common elements into single or fewer lines by replacing the changing values with wildcard character.

**Example**

*Input:*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet_0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet_1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet_2
Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet
Cursus risus at scelerisque mi tempus imperdiet
```

*Output:*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet_*
Cursus risus at * mi tempus imperdiet
```

Is there any tool that I can use for this purpose ?
If not, what are the ways to achieve this?
Thanks

I tried finding any tool which does this but didn't find any.

Comment: You gave us the details of the problem, but you said nothing about your own efforts. What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: I just want to know if there is any tool out there which can do this. I tried searching on google phrasing this question in multiple ways to see if anything exist for this or not, but I didn't find anything (which I've already mentioned in the question). I don't want to spend days doing something for which the solution already exists. That's all I want to know.

Comment: Please check demo1-https://regex101.com/r/aPo9ZZ/1 and demo2- https://regex101.com/r/ZbSASh/1. Would these server your purpose ?

Comment: @novice I want reverse of this. Meaning, I don't want to write regex, I want it as output based on input data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have already found a tool to do this for you.
But if I would do this, I think I would use VSCode to find and replace the regex and then remove the duplicates.

**Generic step/logic:**

- Find all common lines, using regex replace strings with wildcard characters
- Using regex, remove duplicate line (If you want, you may also want to check if there are other IDE or editors that can remove the duplicates for you)

**To do this using VSCode, you may do the following:**

1. Control+F
2. Toggle "Replace mode"
3. Toggle "Use Regular Expression" (the icon with the .* symbol)
4. In the search field, type `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet_(.*)`
5. In the "replace with" field, type `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet_*`
6. Click the Replace All button
7. In the search field, type `^(.*)(\n\1)+$`
8. In the "replace with" field, type `$1`
9. Click the Replace All button

**Repeat the same steps for the other lines:**

- Search: `Cursus risus at (.*) mi tempus imperdiet`
- Replace With: `Cursus risus at * mi tempus imperdiet`